# Efficiently Filter elements in a List based on its indexes

Tags: scala

I am doing an exercise that ask to remove the elements at odd positions.

I wonder if there is a best alternative to what I thought:

```
val a  = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

The first approach:

```
a.zipWithIndex.filter(x => (x._2 & 1) == 1).map(_._1)
```

and the second:

```
a.indices.filter(i => (i & 1) == 1).map(a(_))
```

Am I correct if I think the second approach is more efficient? Since it is not necessary to produce an intermediate list as `zipWithIndex` does?

Comment: I would suggest the opposite. Indexing a `List`, i.e. `a(_)`, is a linear operation inefficient for long lists. To be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a view to avoid intermediate lists:

```
a.view
 .zipWithIndex
 .filter(x => (x._2 & 1) == 1)
 .map(_._1)
 .force
```

This will only traverse `a` once when `force` is called.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `collect` method on the zipped list, might be a bit clearer

```
a.zipWithIndex.collect{
  case (x,i) if i % 2 == 1 => x
}
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YbureiX/0

I am not sure about the efficiency though

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid formation of intermediate collection by using `withFilter`, also you can convert list to Vector to extract element at particular indices in constant time:

```
  val a: Vector[Int] = List(1,2,3,4,5,6).toVector
  val res: Seq[Int] = a.indices.withFilter(i => (i & 1) == 1).map(a(_))
  println(res)
```

Comment: Converting the list to a `Vector` is not done in constant time though..

Comment: but accessing the element will be in constant time

Comment: `a.indices` runs in constant time (it's definition is just `0 until length`). While `a.toVector.indices` will run in linear time, because it has to copy all elements into a new `Vector`. There is not point in converting the `List` to a `Vector`.